# Creating a 2 dimentional system array FROM SCRATCH

Tags: powershell

I always fall into this trap. This is but the latest example.
I have this code that extracts versions of SCCM2007 installed components in a **system array**:

```
$envComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
[System.Management.ManagementObject]$AgentGUID = Get-WmiObject -Computer $envComputerName -Namespace root\ccm -Class CCM_Client -ErrorAction Stop
[System.Management.ManagementObject]$ScanSource = Get-WmiObject -Computer $envComputerName -Namespace root\ccm\SoftwareUpdates\WUAhandler -Class CCM_UpdateSource -ErrorAction Stop
[System.Array]$InstalledComponents = Get-WmiObject -Computer $envComputerName -Namespace root\ccm -Class CCM_InstalledComponent -ErrorAction Stop
$HighestComponentVer = $InstalledComponents | sort version | select version -last 1
[Array]$MyInstalledComponents = $InstalledComponents | sort DisplayName | select DisplayName,Name,version
```

What is really neat about this system array is that the columns are **labelled**.

```
#DisplayName                                                  Name                                                         version      
#-----------                                                  ----                                                         -------      
#CCM Framework                                                CcmFramework                                                 4.0.6487.2196
#CCM Policy Agent                                             CcmPolicyAgent                                               4.0.6487.2000
#CCM Status Agent                                             CcmStatusAgent                                               4.0.6487.2000
#SMS Client Core Components                                   SmsClient                                                    4.0.6487.2000
#SMS Operating System Deployment                              SmsOSDeployment                                              4.0.6487.2000
#SMS OutOfBand Management Agent                               SmsOutOfBandManagement                                       4.0.6487.2000
#SMS Power Management Agent                                   SmsPowerManagement                                           4.0.6487.2157
#SMS Remote Control Agent                                     SmsRemoteTools                                               4.0.6487.2000
#SMS Shared Components                                        SmsCommon                                                    4.0.6487.2000
#SMS Software Distribution Agent                              SmsSoftwareDistribution                                      4.0.6487.2160
#SMS Software Metering Agent                                  SmsSoftwareMetering                                          4.0.6487.2000
#SMS Software Updates Agent                                   SmsSoftwareUpdate                                            4.0.6487.2188
#SMS Source List Update Agent                                 SmsSourceUpdateAgent                                         4.0.6487.2000
#SMS Task Sequence                                            SmsTaskSequence                                              4.0.6487.2179
```

Heck, even this works: `$MyInstalledComponents.version`

I want to compare the versions and need to create a another system array to compare against. The best I can do is this:

```
$SCCM2007ComponentMinVersions = 
@("CCM Framework","CcmFramework","4.0.6487.2196"),
("CCM Policy Agent","CcmPolicyAgent","4.0.6487.2000"),
("CCM Status Agent","CcmStatusAgent","4.0.6487.2000"),
("SMS Client Core Components","SmsClient","4.0.6487.2000"),
("SMS Inventory Agent","SmsInventory","4.0.6487.2184"),
("SMS Operating System Deployment","SmsOSDeployment","4.0.6487.2000"),
("SMS OutOfBand Management Agent","SmsOutOfBandManagement","4.0.6487.2000"),
("SMS Power Management Agent","SmsPowerManagement","4.0.6487.2157"),
("SMS Remote Control Agent","SmsRemoteTools","4.0.6487.2000"),
("SMS Shared Components","SmsCommon","4.0.6487.2000"),
("SMS Software Distribution Agent","SmsSoftwareDistribution","4.0.6487.2160"),
("SMS Software Metering Agent","SmsSoftwareMetering","4.0.6487.2000"),
("SMS Software Updates Agent","SmsSoftwareUpdate","4.0.6487.2188"),
("SMS Source List Update Agent","SmsSourceUpdateAgent","4.0.6487.2000"),
("SMS Task Sequence","SmsTaskSequence","4.0.6487.2179")
```

But this is a System array of system arrays. And I don't get labels for my columns either.

Is there a way to create this from scratch or do you only get the labels when a PowerShell command or WMI returns the array? And if so, why?
What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: I don't know what you want to compare versions against. I gather `$myinstalledcomponents` is one of the comparands, but what is the other? FWIW, generally people call arrays in PS "arrays". You can create and manipulate PS arrays without explicitly using System.Array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result from the WMI-query is an array of objects which all have the properties `DisplayName`, `Name` and `Version`. That's why you have the columns. To quickly make a similar array for you minimum compnent versions, I would use:

```
$SCCM2007ComponentMinVersions = @'
"DisplayName","Name","Version"
"CCM Framework","CcmFramework","4.0.6487.2196"
"CCM Policy Agent","CcmPolicyAgent","4.0.6487.2000"
"CCM Status Agent","CcmStatusAgent","4.0.6487.2000"
"SMS Client Core Components","SmsClient","4.0.6487.2000"
"SMS Inventory Agent","SmsInventory","4.0.6487.2184"
"SMS Operating System Deployment","SmsOSDeployment","4.0.6487.2000"
"SMS OutOfBand Management Agent","SmsOutOfBandManagement","4.0.6487.2000"
"SMS Power Management Agent","SmsPowerManagement","4.0.6487.2157"
"SMS Remote Control Agent","SmsRemoteTools","4.0.6487.2000"
"SMS Shared Components","SmsCommon","4.0.6487.2000"
"SMS Software Distribution Agent","SmsSoftwareDistribution","4.0.6487.2160"
"SMS Software Metering Agent","SmsSoftwareMetering","4.0.6487.2000"
"SMS Software Updates Agent","SmsSoftwareUpdate","4.0.6487.2188"
"SMS Source List Update Agent","SmsSourceUpdateAgent","4.0.6487.2000"
"SMS Task Sequence","SmsTaskSequence","4.0.6487.2179"
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv | Select-Object DisplayName, Name, @{n="Version";e={ $_.Version -as [version] }}
```

Sample output:

```
PS C:\Users\frode> $SCCM2007ComponentMinVersions

DisplayName                     Name                    Version      
-----------                     ----                    -------      
CCM Framework                   CcmFramework            4.0.6487.2196
CCM Policy Agent                CcmPolicyAgent          4.0.6487.2000
CCM Status Agent                CcmStatusAgent          4.0.6487.2000
```

This also converts `Version` to a Version-object which can easily be compared to other version-objects (you need to convert the String-valus from `CCM_InstalledComponents`, see sample below). But personally, I would use a hashtable and not afor your minimumversions-list as it's easier to compare against after. Ex:

```
#Create hashtable for minimumversions
$SCCM2007ComponentMinVersions = @{}

#Fill hashtable with csv-data
@'
"DisplayName","Name","Version"
"CCM Framework","CcmFramework","4.0.6487.2196"
"CCM Policy Agent","CcmPolicyAgent","4.0.6487.2000"
"CCM Status Agent","CcmStatusAgent","4.0.6487.2000"
"SMS Client Core Components","SmsClient","4.0.6487.2000"
"SMS Inventory Agent","SmsInventory","4.0.6487.2184"
"SMS Operating System Deployment","SmsOSDeployment","4.0.6487.2000"
"SMS OutOfBand Management Agent","SmsOutOfBandManagement","4.0.6487.2000"
"SMS Power Management Agent","SmsPowerManagement","4.0.6487.2157"
"SMS Remote Control Agent","SmsRemoteTools","4.0.6487.2000"
"SMS Shared Components","SmsCommon","4.0.6487.2000"
"SMS Software Distribution Agent","SmsSoftwareDistribution","4.0.6487.2160"
"SMS Software Metering Agent","SmsSoftwareMetering","4.0.6487.2000"
"SMS Software Updates Agent","SmsSoftwareUpdate","4.0.6487.2188"
"SMS Source List Update Agent","SmsSourceUpdateAgent","4.0.6487.2000"
"SMS Task Sequence","SmsTaskSequence","4.0.6487.2179"
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv | ForEach-Object { $SCCM2007ComponentMinVersions.Add($_.Name, ($_.Version -as [version])) }

#Sample WMI-output
$InstalledComponents = @'
"DisplayName","Name","Version"
"CCM Framework","CcmFramework","4.0.6487.2195"
"CCM Policy Agent","CcmPolicyAgent","4.0.6487.2000"
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv 


#Find old components
$InstalledComponents | Where-Object { ($_.Version -as [version]) -lt $SCCM2007ComponentMinVersions[$_.Name] }
```

Output:

```
DisplayName   Name         Version
-----------   ----         -------
CCM Framework CcmFramework 4.0.6487.2195
```

Comment: Not what I wanted but what I needed! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The value returned from your call is not a 2 dimensional array, it's an array of objects with properties, that's why you get column names and can use dot notation.

You can create a `[PSObject]` from a `[hashtable]` and have an array of those:

```
$SCCM2007ComponentMinVersions = @(
    @{
        DisplayName = "CCM Framework"
        Name = "CcmFramework"
        Version = "4.0.6487.2196"
    },
    @{
        DisplayName = "CCM Policy Agent"
        Name = "CcmPolicyAgent"
        Version = "4.0.6487.2000"
    }
)
```

That makes an array of `[hashtable]`s, which might be enough. To make `[PSObjects]`:

```
$SCCM2007ComponentMinVersions = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        DisplayName = "CCM Framework"
        Name = "CcmFramework"
        Version = "4.0.6487.2196"
    },
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        DisplayName = "CCM Policy Agent"
        Name = "CcmPolicyAgent"
        Version = "4.0.6487.2000"
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to make an array of objects with named properties.

- `$var = @()` makes an array
- `$var = @{Key="Value"}` makes a hash table
- `$var = new-object psobject -property $hashtable` makes a new object with named properties that correspond to a given hashtable

With that in mind, check this out:

```
$SCCM2007ComponentMinVersions = @(
    (new-object psobject -property @{DisplayName="CCM Framework";Name="CcmFramework";Version="4.0.6487.2196"}),
    (new-object psobject -property @{DisplayName="CCM Policy Agent";Name="CcmPolicyAgent";Version="4.0.6487.2000"})
)
```

That should give you an array of objects that you can manipulate nicely.

```
PS H:\> $SCCM2007ComponentMinVersions 

DisplayName        Version        Name
-----------        -------        ----
CCM Framework      4.0.6487.2196  CcmFramework
CCM Policy Agent   4.0.6487.2000  CcmPolicyAgent
```

As an added benefit, this type of data structure works great when piped to `Export-CSV` (or `ConvertTo-Csv` if you just want to test it out in the console) and similar methods of displaying tabular data.